# Error warning for backward compatibility

Tags: errors, preamble

Recently I have been using Overleaf and Texworks for my latex and I seem to be getting the error:

> Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable tick labels; missing features). Consider writing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.15} into your preamble. on input line 42.

but I dont actually understand what it getting at, I never had issue on Texmaker but this comes up in open leaf and tex works.

What confusing me is what it is classing as preamble?

Does anyone have knowledge of this error?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. But what is your compilable code? Can you could put into your question, please?

Comment: The tex version of overleafe is probably newer as the one you are using on your computer, that's why you don't get the message in texmaker. To fix this add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}` to your preamble (the part of the code before `\begin{document}`). If this does not help, please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).